# upload a file without having the submit button in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

```
I want to upload a file without using the submit button. The file must be uploaded at the moment the user picks it from browse file window.
```

Now please do provide some ajax code or some jquery to upload the file and also how to delete the file.

```
Please provide the control view for this.
View>>>

<form action="FileUploadPost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label for="file1">Filename1:</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file3" />

        <label for="file2">Filename2:</label>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="file4" />

</form>
```

Controller>>>

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery file uploader control for your requirements. 
It provides functionality to upload file with both "By Clicking on the button" and "Auto Upload".

**Auto Upload** : This functionality will upload file as soon as you select the file.

See [Ajax File Upload](http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery) for step by step implementation.